# Select2 and laravel 5.3 forms

Tags: laravel, controller, jquery-select2

I have a laravel 5.3 app and i have a New Posts page with:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label for="tags"> Select Tags</label>
    <select class="custom-select form-control" name="tags" id="tag-select" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
      <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}} </option>
    @endforeach      
    </select>
</div>
```

Using select2 `https://select2.github.io/`

Tag Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Class tag
 * @package App\Models
 * @version September 20, 2016, 5:31 am UTC
 */
class tag extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'tags';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [

    ];
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Post');
    }
    public function movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Movies');
    }


}
```

At the controller when i `dd(request())` i only get the value of the last tag i clicked.

---

Please help, how can i get the input to pass all the values and how to get them at the controller.

Anything else needed please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `blade templating` ? 
do it like so :

```
{{ Form::select('tags', \App\tags::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(), null,['class'=>'select2']) }}
```

inside your `div` :

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">

 {{ Form::label('Select Tags', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
 {{ Form::select('tags[]', \App\tags::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(), null,['class'=>'select2']) }}

</div>
```

Comment: Ok i tried it but i have an error:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column tags.post_id' in where clause (SQL: select * from tags where tags.post_id = 1 and tags.post_id is not null and tags.deleted_at is null)`

Where the hell its the blade calling post_id?

Comment: If you try to get `tags` from your controller doesn't show the error ?

Comment: No, it gives me the array with the 3 tags i have in the database. When i erase the third parameter for `Form::select` (The null parameter) the view renders without the error, but the select tag renders without a class and i need it for the select2 plugin.

Comment: ok then pass the result as an array into the `{{Form::Select}}`

Comment: Ok, seems like the problem was the `hasMany`  relation to posts in the `Post.php` model.
 I already made the view render and everything its great, cleaner with blade templates but when i post the form, at the controller i `dd(request()->tags) ` and i only get the id of the last tag selected again.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it are you still facing the problem ?

Comment: Yes, i still get only one id when the select it´s multiple, and thanks for the blade template, much cleaner now.

Comment: Oh you want multiple Oops ... just change the name and make it `tags[]` @Krubbit